# Choice of backend technologies to be used to build a full fledged blogging application with front end being of Vue2 js

Tags: vuejs2

I am building a full fledged blogging application .As I am primarily into front end development I have almost decided what front end technologies I will be using for my app.(decided on using Vue js) .But now confused which technology stack technology goes well with VueJs .the database choice also not decided upon 
yet.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If it's only a blogging platform you can try content as a service platforms like [contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) or [dotcms](https://dotcms.com/solutions/content-as-a-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really understand why you get point-reductions..

Actually, you already did the hard part, deciding the front end development technology.

If you had decided to go with angular or ember, it would have been quit hard to integrate a Server side technology (i'm not talking about database only). If you need some server side rendering or a CMS, vue integrates very good with these technologies.

I've used vuejs2 with .Net MVC, .net ASP, Umbraco CMS and Sitecore CMS (based on .nets ASPX) and works very well, (also laracast works very well for php, but I haven't used it).

You can find some samples of integrating vuejs with server side technologies in my  [github account](https://github.com/pimboden)

Hope it helps